# Why Spring (launch by Tomcat) will load SpingBoot starter (I put it to Tomcat/lib.)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I write a Spring Boot starter, as below

```
package boot.com.raycloud.project.monitor.common;

import...

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnSpringBoot
public class MonitorAutoConfigure {
    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean securityManagerServletContextListener() {
        System.out.println("=====init servlet Listener=====");
        ServletListenerRegistrationBean<XXListener> listenerRegistrationBean = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<XXListener>();
        listenerRegistrationBean.setListener(new SecurityManagerServletContextListener());
        listenerRegistrationBean.setOrder(10);
        listenerRegistrationBean.setEnabled(true);
        return listenerRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

I tested it under Spring Boot 1.x and Spring Boot 2.x, it worked.

But when I put it Tomcat/lib (a normal Spring project (3.2.4.Release), not Spring Boot). It occurs some error.

The stack is as follows:

```
严重: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/data/project/item-publish-web/tomcat/lib/project-monitor-boot-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/raycloud/project/monitor/autoconfigure1/Boot1.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: URL [jar:file:/data/project/item-publish-web/tomcat/lib/project-monitor-boot-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/raycloud/project/monitor/autoconfigure1/Boot1.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5141)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5664)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: URL [jar:file:/data/project/item-publish-web/tomcat/lib/project-monitor-boot-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/raycloud/project/monitor/autoconfigure1/Boot1.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:56)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:266)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:53)
... 35 more
```

tomcat/lib picture:
[image: tomcat/lib picture]

I found that the `asm` version is too low to cause, but why Spring Boot starter will be load by Spring.

Comment: Because you've configured Spring to scan the classpath to find components, and thus... it does it.

Comment: @JBNizet nope , specially i update package name 
 like `boot.com.raycloud.project.monitor.common` . then i Comment `@Configuration` and `@ConditionalOnSpringBoot` . all failed.   crazy

Comment: Are you claiming you didn't configure spring to do a component scan? The annotations are irrelevant. The classes are scanned precisely to know if they contain an annotated component.

Comment: no, this jar is inner , developers can't get it or declare except me. only i can write or update this jar.

Comment: So what? It's in the classpath. So it's scanned. Do you really think that somewhere in the Spring code there is a test that checks if the jar has been created by shun chen, and that skips it if that's the case?

Comment: of course not, but when jvm load a class or jar ,There must be a place to show or the hermit has made a declaration. , i know `new` is impossible。`class.forName` is impossible  ,  last  `ClassLoader` i don't known, why Spring will scan "me". i don't declare any message except `spring.factories`. this is used by springboot? isn't it?

Comment: classpath scanning, as its name indicates, consists in scanning the classed in the classpath. The class doesn't need to be used or instantiated anywhere. If it's in the classpath, it's scanned.

Comment: i don't think so , spring will scan but just scan the path i declare , as we known , i can't declare it by myself。

Comment: Well, ask the question to yourself then, not to us. And live with the fact that the error and its stack trace contradicts what you think.

Comment: Apologize for my tone，And the entry point is why stater will be load.